# Git pull incorrectly prioritises old commits 

Tags: git, merge

At my office we're transitioning to Git, and at the moment I'm using Git-SVN to do the following workflow:

```
 git svn rebase 
 git checkout -B FEATURE_NUMBER
```

*do work, while committing locally*

```
git checkout master
git svn rebase
git merge --squash FEATURE_NUMBER
```

*fix any conflicts, run tests etc*

```
git commit -a -m "Actual Commit Message for everyone else"
git svn dcommit
```

That works fine, but I also travel between offices and use different computers, so I've been using a private GitHub repo to push my branches around if I'm not finished.

The workflow for that is:

```
 git svn rebase 
 git checkout -B FEATURE_NUMBER
```

*do work, while committing locally*

*now I want to move offices*

git push origin FEATURE_NUMBER

*go to new office*

```
 git svn rebase 
 git checkout -B FEATURE_NUMBER
 git pull origin FEATURE_NUMBER
```

However, the problem with that, is that a heap of conflicts occur. It seems to be thinking that on Github, I've undid all the changes that my team have made since I originally rebased in the main office. Basically its prioritising the old commits on GitHub (ie, from before the rebase) over the new commits from the SVN server.

Is there some way I can make it merge nicely?

Answer (score 1):

Are you ever doing the `git svn rebase` while on the feature branch? Note that `git svn rebase` does a real rebase, i.e. creating new commits with a different parent. Also note that `git pull` automatically creates a merge. The conflicts are a result of trying to merge the same changes (those on `FEATURE_NUMBER` before you moved offices) found in different commits from two different places in the tree.

To avoid this problem, you can avoid a pull, and instead request a `git fetch`. It merely fetches the new commits into `origin/FEATURE_NUMBER`, so you can do with them whatever you want, such as:

```
# fetch new work from GitHub into origin/FEATURE_BRANCH
git fetch origin
# reset FEATURE_NUMBER to the latest GitHub
git checkout -B FEATURE_NUMBER origin/FEATURE_NUMBER
# reparent those commits on top of the latest svn
git svn rebase
```

Comment: git svn rebase fails with 'unable to determine upstream svn information from working tree history'. I tried git merge master after rebasing there, but it does a 3 way merge with the base as a blank file, so it thinks the whole file is changed and its all in conflict. 

Using your fetch /branch method, I can go to master and do a merge --squash, and then use beyond compare to change which file is the base which merges it ok, but still wish it was automatic

Comment: On another branch I tried, it said that everything was in conflict once I did the git svn rebase

Comment: I don't understand why `git svn rebase` would fail; back when I still used git-svn, you could rebase from any branch. On this other branch, are you sure that the conflict wasn't real, i.e. that someone didn't commit the same change you were trying to rebase? Maybe your git-svn installation is corrupted in a way that makes it unable to correctly determine where the non-svn commits begin.